# Parsing a struct typedef in emacs semantics when typedef and struct in different files

Tags: emacs, emacs24, emacs-semantic

Supposing I have as typedef struct definition like this:

```
typedef struct IP_ROUTE_ IP_ROUTE;

struct IP_ROUTE_ {
    unsigned    prefix;
    unsigned    mask;
    unsigned    next_hop;
};
```

All is fine. Semantic parses it nicely and if I do..

```
IP_ROUTE   r;

r->
```

I get struct specific completion popup menu. No problem with that.

However if typedef is in one file and the struct declaration is in another file then I have problems. There is no completion popup menu.

ip_route.h

```
typedef struct IP_ROUTE_ IP_ROUTE;
```

ip_route_internal.h

```
struct IP_ROUTE_ {
    unsigned    prefix;
    unsigned    mask;
    unsigned    next_hop;
};
```

Then the completion does not work.

Comment: It should work fine if your includes are correct, which I don't see since you haven't listed the updated ip_route.c file.

Comment: **Thank You**
Yes.. I was looking at another file that did not have internal.h included. After I sorted out the #includes it worked fine.

WoW. It is **that** intelligent !! If the struct definition is incomplete then it will not auto-complete ....